# Why are there disabled buttons in HighStock Range Selector? And how to enable them?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having an issue with rangeSelector in HighCharts/HighStocks. For some reason, smaller selections are disables or are getting disabled after making a range selection. My question is this, how can I make sure that all range selection buttons are active since data is available for a specific range. 
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/20/) example.
Any advice is much appreciated.

Here is an example of my rangeSelector:

```
rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            },{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 15,
                text: '15m'
            },{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 60,
                text: '1h'
            },{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1day'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1mo'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6mo'
            },{
                type: 'ytd',
                text: 'YTD'
            },
            {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 2
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the data source you are using: http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js

Note that the most granular it gets is one value per day. If highcharts let you zoom in to a day or less, it would just be displaying one value... not very useful.

This is expected behavior. With a more granular source, everything will be just fine!

Comment: That makes sense. Highcharts cannot zoom in to points it does not have. Thank you for clearing it up for me.